# Some subpanels are empty in contact module's detail view

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Some subpanels are empty in contact module's detail view. Permissions are Okey and I did both "Rebuild Relationships" and "Quick Repair and Rebuild".

FYI : I am using SuiteCRM Version 7.9.5 Sugar Version 6.5.24 (version de construction 509)

Please see attachment below :

[image]

Best regards.

Comment: You should include anything else you may have done to the site before encountering this problem. You've shown no code, or any details that might have led you to this.

Comment: Thank you Reisclef for your fast anwser, I didn't change anything I just upgrade my instance of suiteCRM to a newly one. Do you have any idea ? what kind of code or part you want me to show ?

Comment: If you upgraded from a previous version, you might want to show any code that was changed in regards to the subpanels below Contacts. Also, you might show what it looked like before you upgraded.

Comment: My code is clean Reisclef I didn't any changes !!

Comment: Okay, when you said you upgraded, and provided no history, it was pure guesswork. If you change the language to English, do the titles show? I'm not sure why something like that would happen, but I don't know much about SuiteCRM specifically.

Comment: Thank you Reisclef for your help I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it ! For somehow I found in custom/Extensions/modules/Leads/Ext/Vardefs/file.php a definition for contact module:

$dictionary ['Contact'] ['fields'] ['field_name'] ['labelValue'] = 'a_value';

So the right definition instead is :
$dictionary ['Lead'] ['fields'] ['field_name'] ['labelValue'] = 'a_value';

And this impacted also the subpanels in contact modules.

Best regards.